# Why Case statement returns 1 as output in this situation?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

**1st Situation:**
Why Case statement returns 1 as output in this situation.
First i checked with this query:

```
DECLARE @VAR INT=0

SELECT CASE
         WHEN @VAR = ' ' THEN 1
         ELSE 0
       END as empty_string
```

**output**:

```
empty_string
1
```

After this situation i tried like this:
**2nd Situation:**
Why Different value coming whenever assigning to Local varible?

```
DECLARE @var1 INT =' '

SELECT @var1 AS empty_assighn

SELECT ' ' AS empty_string
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
empty_assighn
0
empty_string
-----------
```

Then I found whenever assigning it take ' '(empty string) as zero value.so that's why i get 1 as output in 1st situation. But why it take like this? what is the Reason behind that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Because, below query returns `0`

```
SELECT CAST(' ' AS INT)
```

When you do this check `CASE WHEN @VAR = ' ' THEN 1`, right hand side of the condition is converted to variable's datatype (`INT`). So condition results as `True`.

Comment: So ' '(empty string) implicitly converted into int and by default it shows zero as output.

Comment: @AjaynaiduPappala : yes, implicitly converted to `int`, hence resulted as '0'. Eventually selected `1` as output.

Answer (score 0):

By default sqlserver will try to convert value (called implicitly conversion) as per datatype we define. 
Check this [link](http://www.tizag.com/sqlTutorial/sqldatatypes.php), [msdn link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191530.aspx) for more understanding.

When your value is not able to convert internally, it throw the error as 'Conversion failed when converting the youardatatype value to data type int.'

When we use cast or convert function, its called 'exlicitly conversion'

Check this example :

```
This will convert without error 

select cast('' as int)
select cast('  ' as int)
select cast(null as int)
select cast(cast( null as datetime) as int)
select cast( cast(0 as decimal) as int)
select cast( cast(1 as bit) as int)
select cast( cast(11 as bit) as int)
select cast( cast(0.0 as decimal) as int)
select cast( cast(0.1 as numeric(18,2)) as int)


This will throw error because it is not have int value
select cast('a' as int)
select cast(' , ' as int)
```

The same thing will work for other datattype like `Datetime`

```
--As datetime format in sqlserver is yyyy-mm-dd so, if we give this format in string it will convert
select cast('' as datetime)
select cast('20151211' as datetime)  --today's date
select cast('2015-12-11' as datetime)
select cast('2015-12-11' as datetime)
select cast('12-11-2015' as datetime)

--this throw error
select cast('2015-24-11' as datetime)
```